# How to get the letters of a string which starts with a certain character avoiding other special characters

Tags: java, regex, velocity

I have the below String.

```
#firstName.concat(' ').concat(#lastName)
```

I need to get the names that start with "#". But it shouldn't be followed by other special characters. So in this case, I need "firstName" and "lastNAme" as outputs. I tried the below method. But it throws pattern not matching exeption. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
private static void getTokens(String value) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(^#\\)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
    String s = m.group(1);
    System.out.println("answer : " + s);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a simple regex like

```
#(\w+)
```

to match `#` and then capture 1+ subsequent word chars with `\w+`, and then you need to run the Matcher with `.find()` inside `while` loop.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#(\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
while (m.find()) {
    String s = m.group(1);
    System.out.println("answer : " + s);
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/dcDkcQ)

Comment: if I am to search for letters starting with $, should I escape it?

Comment: Yes, sure, `"\\$(\\w+)"`, or put it into a character class, `"[$](\\w+)"`. Or join with the above regex: `"[$#](\\w+)"`.